# not able to add proper rule for firebase custom claim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jwt, firebase-security

I have created an auth token using Firebase documentation for ruby but then when I am trying to access the custom claim in the data security rules it does not work.

my JWT creation code looks something like this

```
$service_account_email = "service-account@my-project-abc123.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
$private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n..."
  now_seconds = Time.now.to_i
  payload = {:iss => $service_account_email,
             :sub => $service_account_email,
             :aud => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
             :iat => now_seconds,
             :exp => now_seconds+(60*60), # Maximum expiration time is one hour
             :uid => uid,
             :claims => {:modify_vessels => true}}
 jwt_token = JWT.encode payload, private_key, "RS256"

render json: { :status => "ok", :email => usr, :jwt_token => jwt_token, :uid => uid } and return
```

I have tried below rules for accessing claims object but none of them work

```
{
  "rules": {
    "vessels" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read":"auth.token.modify_vessels === true",
            ".write":"auth.token.modify_vessels === true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "rules": {
    "vessels" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read":"auth.claims.modify_vessels === true",
            ".write":"auth.claims.modify_vessels === true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please Note :- I can do auth.uid and it works

Any help on this will be helpful

Comment: Lets go for the blatantly obvious question: Are you sure the custom claim is set (properly)?

Comment: when I am decoding the JWT i can see the claims: { modify_vessels: true } and I do not know any other way of checking this as I am not using any admin SDK's